# ngFor in ionic 2 throwing "error trying to diff"

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am working on Ionic 2 project.
I am populating a select input type with data from database.
I am using ngFor for displaying data.
On select input type (change) I want to fetch additional data but ionic 2 is throwing error "Error trying to diff".
I am stuck right now. I have posted issue on github but received no response.
And my array of data is not empty.
Working on latest alpha of ionic 2 (alpha49)

select input code is given below

```ts
<select (change)="getDetails()" [(ngModel)]="userList">
    <option *ngFor="#name of userList">{{name.name}}</option>
</select>
```

and in typescript file I have a function

```ts
getDetails() {
    console.log("ok");
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code here, so we can see what you have tried?

Comment: How does `userList` look like?

Comment: public userList = [
        { name: 'Jilles', age: 21 },
        { name: 'Todd', age: 24 },
        { name: 'Lisa', age: 18 }
    ];

Comment: I've got the same problem, can you post the link to your issue on GitHub?

Comment: I found my mistake, the list I passed turned out to just be an object. Make sure userList is really a list

Comment: I closed my issue on github.

Answer (score 4):

been a while but you should not be binding the value of the selector to userList because it will overwrite your array.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the items in the `userList` are not unique. Probably your using mock data and copy pasted the items.

```
var userList = ['nicojs', 'nicojs' /* "error trying to diff" */];
```

Angular 2 needs to keep track of which item it is enumerating, just as AngularJS does. So each item has to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by warren, in my case as well i was using the selector array as my ngModel which was overwriting my selector list on change.

I changed my code from:

```
<select class="form-controlRT-sm" [(ngModel)]="*dashBoardData.StatusList*">
 <option *ngFor="let item of dashBoardData.StatusList" [value]="item.Key">{{item.Value}}</option>
</select>
```

To:

```
<select class="form-controlRT-sm" [(ngModel)]="*dashBoardData.status*">
<option *ngFor="let item of dashBoardData.StatusList" [value]="item.Key">{{item.Value}}</option>
 </select>
```